# Remote listening of UNIX sockets

Tags: unix, sockets

I'd like to be able to remotely listen to UNIX sockets in order to make programs such as `dtach`, which only support listening to UNIX sockets, work remotely. I've read about `socat` and how it's able to forward UNIX sockets to TCP sockets and vice-versa, but in practice I haven't been able to make this work. So, through `socat` or any other means, how can one remotely listen to UNIX sockets?

(If you happen to know how to make `dtach` work remotely, then that's fine too. This question is simply an abstract question to the actual problem.)

Answer (score 7):

I just found that this works:

```
remotehost$ socat TCP-LISTEN:6066 UNIX-CONNECT:/tmp/a.socket
localhost$ socat UNIX-LISTEN:/tmp/a.socket TCP:remotehost:6066
```

Answer (score 0):

SSH can forward Unix domain sockets with -L and -R the same way that it forwards TCP ports. Example: `ssh -L ./mydocker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock example.com`

Comment: How? Can you expand on this with an example?

Comment: Added an example.